# Reset default matplotlib colormap values after using 'set_under' or 'set_over'

Tags: python, matplotlib, colormap

This is something that has been bugging me for a while. Whenever I use the `cmap.set_under()` or `cmap.set_over()` methods to change the the color of out of bound values, they seem to apply these changes to ALL instances where I use that colormap. Below is an example of what I am referring to.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np

rand_data = np.random.randint(50, size=(20,20))

plt.figure()
plt.subplot(211)
cmap1 = plt.cm.rainbow
im1 = plt.pcolormesh(rand_data, cmap=cmap1, vmin=10)
im1.cmap.set_under('w')
plt.colorbar(extend='min')

plt.subplot(212)
cmap2 = plt.cm.rainbow
im2 = plt.pcolormesh(rand_data, cmap=cmap2, vmin=10)
im2.cmap.set_under('k')
plt.colorbar(extend='min')

plt.show()
```

Here I am trying to create two plots of the same values. In the first plot, I want all values below 10 to be white. In the second plot, I want all values below 10 to be black. The result is this:

[image]

It appears that the second time I used `set_under` it reset the set_under for all existing plots that use the rainbow colormap. If I use a different colormap in the second plot, I able to set a different `set_under` color:

[image]

Even more bizarre, if use `cmap.set_under()` or `cmap.set_over()` in a function or script, this setting does not reset after exiting that function. That is, if I comment out the lines where I explicitly defined the `set_under` and colors re-run my script, I get the same result as before.

So I have a couple questions:

1. Is there a way to set the color of out-of-bounds values of a colormap for a single plot *without affecting the colormap of any existing plots*?
2. How do I reset the out-of-bounds values to their original colors?

For the second question, I know I can manually add back in the original colors by doing something like this:

```
N = cmap.N
cmap.set_under(cmap(1))
cmap.set_over(cmap(N-1))
```

But, I feel like there should be an easier way.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The behaviour you describe is expected. There is only a single colormap present, which is `plt.cm.rainbow`. When you first `set_under('w')` and later `set_under('k')`, the color for `under` will be black.

What you want to do is actually use two different instances of the same colormap and then change each instance to have a different value for the lower bound.
This can easily be done using `copy`,

```
cmap1 = copy.copy(plt.cm.rainbow)
```

Now manipulating `cmap1` does not change the rainbow colormap itself, such that it is possible to later create another copy of it and apply different settings.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np
import copy

rand_data = np.random.randint(50, size=(20,20))

plt.figure()
plt.subplot(211)
cmap1 = copy.copy(plt.cm.rainbow)
im1 = plt.pcolormesh(rand_data, cmap=cmap1, vmin=10)
im1.cmap.set_under('w')
plt.colorbar(extend='min')

plt.subplot(212)
cmap2 = copy.copy(plt.cm.rainbow)
im2 = plt.pcolormesh(rand_data, cmap=cmap2, vmin=10)
im2.cmap.set_under('k')
plt.colorbar(extend='min')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I didn't even think about making a copy of the colormap. I guess I was under the impression that using `im.cmap.set_under( )` versus just `cmap.set_under` would only change the instance of the colormap used in `im`. But, your explanation makes perfect sense.