# Python: How do I restore the default colormap settings?

Tags: python, matplotlib, colormap

I reset my colormap values, as this person did: [Reset default matplotlib colormap values after using 'set_under' or 'set_over'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42843669/reset-default-matplotlib-colormap-values-after-using-set-under-or-set-over)

I understand I need to use copy to not cause this problem.

My question: how do I restore my colormap settings to their default value? i.e., I don't want set_under('w') to always stay white, I want it back to default settings.

My issue is now every plot that has values < set_under results in white being plotted, when what I'd want is the value to be plotted at the min value (at the min/max limit of the colorbar, instead of replacing the values with white).

Comment: Changing the colormap this way only happens during the current session. Just restarting your program will solve the issue. If you'd write a large program, you'll need to take this warning into account, but for short stand-alone code it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just restart the program.
See [@JohnC's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72410468/python-how-do-i-restore-the-default-colormap-settings/72438545#comment127919907_72410468):

> Changing the colormap this way only happens during the current session. Just restarting your program will solve the issue. If you'd write a large program, you'll need to take this warning into account, but for short stand-alone code it doesn't matter